# Search github Enterprise Organization Repos for string matches

Tags: search, github, repository, github-enterprise

Our repositories are divided into communities (also called Organizations) in GitHub Enterprise. There are, for example, the *BlueMeanies* and the *YellowSubmarines* organizations. Each of these organizations has perhaps a dozen repos, e.g. 
YellowSubmarines/WhiteAlbum, YellowSubmarines/AbbeyRoad, ...

What I would like to do is

> Search: **screendoors** in:code repo:**YellowSubmarines/*** extension:sh

That is, to find all files containing the text *screendoors* in all of the  *repositories* in the YellowSubmarines organization. I do not want to see results from other organizations.

Ideally I'd like to limit the match to "sh" (bash) scripts files as well.

Of course the above syntax doesn't work thus this question.

Any solution is accepted, including using the API.

Comment: Please provide code examples, we don't do your homework but are happy to help you as soon as you put effort into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user:` qualifier searches both users and orgs. (ref: [Search within a user's or organization's repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories))

Therefore:

`user:YellowSubmarines extension:sh screendoors`

is valid. You will need to click on "Code" on the results screen to specifically see the code results, as it defaults to the "Repositories" view.

I have tested this answer using GitHub Enterprise 2.1.11

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it works brilliantly and was completely not expected.